# StreamWriter не хочет записывать в файл ответ

Tags: c#

Программа считывает 2 числа с файла и выполняет мат. действия, а StreamWriter не хочет записывать в файл ответ.

[image: Проблема]

Comment: Пожалуйста, прикрепляйте код текстом, а не картинкой.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Помогаю.

Используйте

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("output.txt"))
{
  ...
}
```

и тогда Вы не ошибетесь в имени переменной, закрывая файл:

```
sr.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Потому что вы повторно пытаетесь закрыть StreamReader, а незакрытый поток StreamWriter и не запишет ничего.